# homestead command not working

Tags: bash, composer-php

I'm updating Laravel's Homestead to work with the new command line tool and I've hit a hurdle early on.

I've already installed the box and installed the tool by running:

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

If I run `~/.composer/vendor/bin/homestead` then I get what I'm looking for.

But if I run just `homestead` on it's own I get:

```
command not found: homestead
```

Here's my path:

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/johndoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/johndoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/Users/johndoe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/johndoe/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Where you can clearly see `~/.composer/vendor/bin` at the front.

Obviously not the end of the world but just wondering if there's anything I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~` character has not been expanded.  Add `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` to the path instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this before init.
EPOCLAB:~ Dev$ PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
EPOCLAB:~ Dev$ homestead init